# Number of times a character appears in a variable with R

Tags: r, frequency

I've a data frame, and one of the variables (w1) is a factor with seven levels. Here are the first few lines:

```
X   number          delta1 tossc w1
1   0.743477269         0   1   <NA>
2   0.742817675         0   1    x1
3   0.867432987         0   1    x5
4   0.535971961         1   1    Group3
5   0.743477269         0   1    x2
6   0.742817675         0   1    x1
7   0.867432987         0   1    <NA>
8   0.535971961         1   1   Group3 or Group4
```

How can find number of times each character has appeared in w1? (for example, x1 appeard 2 times,  x5 appeared 1 time, etc.). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: for example `table(dat$w1)`...

Comment: Thank you. I need to store these numbers in new variables. for example: nx1= # of times x1 has appeared. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution using `merge` and `table`

```
merge(dat,as.data.frame(table(dat$w1)),by.x='w1',by.y='Var1')
                w1 X    number delta1 tossc Freq
1             <NA> 1 0.7434773      0     1    2
2             <NA> 7 0.8674330      0     1    2
3           Group3 4 0.5359720      1     1    1
4 Group3 or Group4 8 0.5359720      1     1    1
5               x1 2 0.7428177      0     1    2
6               x1 6 0.7428177      0     1    2
7               x2 5 0.7434773      0     1    1
8               x5 3 0.8674330      0     1    1
```

Comment: I tried to run this, but i'm getting an error message: Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify valid column(s)

Comment: It's working now! Thanks! But I need to use nx1, nx2, etc.. for further analysis.. how can i do that? Thanks again!

Comment: @Actuary do you mean this ?..`nx1 <- table(dat$w1)['x1']`

Comment: Thanks.. this is what i want! nx1 <- table(dat$w1)['x1']

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be:

```
length(which(dat$w1=="x1"))
```

which can be easily saved as a new variable.